# How to add LI in UL in arbitrary position using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add LI in my existing UL. My HTML is like this:

```
<ul id="friends">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="new">Friend 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="new">Friend 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="new">Friend 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="offline">Friend 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="offline">Friend 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="invited">Friend 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

i know i can use it to add LI at the and

```
$("#friends").append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="new">Friend 1</a></li>');
```

But it will add in last position and i want to add it at first position or in middle. How to specify the position at which I want to insert the LI?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prepend and http://api.jquery.com/after -- just [browse the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) until you find the most useful method for your purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of `append`

```
$("#friends").prepend('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="new">Friend 1</a></li>');
```

To append at particular position you can use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$("#friends li").eq(4).append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="new">Friend 1</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [**prepend**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

```
$("#friends").prepend('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="new">Friend 1</a></li>');
```